# Grizzly + Jersey Listening ONLY on Localhost

Tags: java, jersey, grizzly

I'm using Jersey with an embedded version of Grizzly and I'd like to bind/listen on localhost ONLY. I'm creating the ThreadSelector using the GrizzlyWebContainerFactory with the create call:

```
threadSelector = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create("http://127.0.0.1:8080/", initParams);
```

This works, but I'm still able to hit the server from an external machine. How can I get it to bind to/listen on ONLY localhost?

This is for configuration stuff, so I don't want anything off box to be able to connect to this server.

Answer (score 18):

I was able to do this using the hostname `localhost` in Jersey 2.3.1 with an embedded version of Grizzly:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
// ...
GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
    URI.create("http://localhost:9580/my-app/")
);
```

Testing results in:

```
> curl -I http://myhost.com:9580/my-app
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Whereas when starting the Grizzly server with the URIs `"http://0.0.0.0:9580/my-app/"`, or  `"http://myhost.com:9580/my-app/"` I am be able to hit it with

```
> curl -I http://myhost.com:9580/my-app
HTTP/1.1 200 Not Found
...
```

---

Here's a table of which hosts work with which URLs when using `GrizzlyHttpServerFactory`. No surprises here, as far as I understand:

```
# For http://0.0.0.0:9575/my-app      | Works?
curl -I http://0.0.0.0:9575/my-app    | Yes
curl -I http://127.0.0.1:9575/my-app  | Yes
curl -I http://localhost:9575/my-app  | Yes
curl -I http://myhost.com:9575/my-app | Yes
                                      | 
# For http://127.0.0.1:9575/my-app    | 
# For http://localhost:9575/my-app    |
curl -I http://0.0.0.0:9575/my-app    | Yes
curl -I http://127.0.0.1:9575/my-app  | Yes
curl -I http://localhost:9575/my-app  | Yes
curl -I http://myhost.com:9575/my-app | No
                                      | 
# For http://myhost.com:9585/my-app   | 
curl -I http://0.0.0.0:9585/my-app    | No
curl -I http://127.0.0.1:9585/my-app  | No
curl -I http://localhost:9575/my-app  | No
curl -I http://myhost.com:9585/my-app | Yes
```

Answer (score -2):

You can easily extend the GrizzlyWebContainerFactory to support this requirement (since the class is final, I have created a self-contained utility that allows you to bind the listening socket to localhost). You could use this utility as:

```
SelectorThread threadSelector = GrizzlyWebContainerFactoryUtil.create("http://127.0.0.1:8080/", initParams, true);
```

Setting the last parameter to true forces it to bind to localhost. The only code I added to support this requirement is:

```
selectorThread.setAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
```

The entire utility class is shown below:

```
import com.sun.grizzly.http.SelectorThread;
import com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter;
import com.sun.grizzly.standalone.StaticStreamAlgorithm;
import com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Adapter;
import com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter;
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Map;

public class GrizzlyWebContainerFactoryUtil {

  public static SelectorThread create(String u, Map<String, String> initParams, boolean localHostOnly)
          throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
      if (u == null)
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("The URI must not be null");

      return create(URI.create(u), initParams, localHostOnly);
  }

  public static SelectorThread create(URI u, Map<String, String> initParams, boolean localHostOnly) throws IOException {
    return create(u, ServletContainer.class, initParams, localHostOnly);
  }

  public static SelectorThread create(URI u, Class<? extends Servlet> c,
                                      Map<String, String> initParams, boolean localHostOnly) throws IOException {
    if (u == null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The URI must not be null");

    ServletAdapter adapter = new ServletAdapter();
    if (initParams == null) {
      adapter.addInitParameter(ClasspathResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CLASSPATH,
        System.getProperty("java.class.path").replace(File.pathSeparatorChar, ';'));
    } else {
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : initParams.entrySet()) {
        adapter.addInitParameter(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
      }
    }

    adapter.setServletInstance(getInstance(c));

    String path = u.getPath();
    if (path == null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The URI path, of the URI " + u +
        ", must be non-null");
    else if (path.length() == 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The URI path, of the URI " + u +
        ", must be present");
    else if (path.charAt(0) != '/')
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The URI path, of the URI " + u +
        ". must start with a '/'");

    if (path.length() > 1) {
      if (path.endsWith("/"))
        path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1);
      adapter.setContextPath(path);
    }

    return create(u, adapter, localHostOnly);
  }

  private static Servlet getInstance(Class<? extends Servlet> c) {
    try {
      return c.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new ContainerException(e);
    }
  }


  public static SelectorThread create(URI u, Adapter adapter, boolean localHostOnly)
    throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
    if (u == null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The URI must not be null");

    // TODO support https
    final String scheme = u.getScheme();
    if (!scheme.equalsIgnoreCase("http"))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The URI scheme, of the URI " + u +
        ", must be equal (ignoring case) to 'http'");

    if (adapter instanceof GrizzlyAdapter) {
      GrizzlyAdapter ga = (GrizzlyAdapter) adapter;
      ga.setResourcesContextPath(u.getRawPath());
    }

    final SelectorThread selectorThread = new SelectorThread();

    selectorThread.setAlgorithmClassName(StaticStreamAlgorithm.class.getName());

    final int port = (u.getPort() == -1) ? 80 : u.getPort();
    selectorThread.setPort(port);

    if (localHostOnly) {
      selectorThread.setAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
    }
    selectorThread.setAdapter(adapter);

    try {
      selectorThread.listen();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
      IOException _e = new IOException();
      _e.initCause(e);
      throw _e;
    }
    return selectorThread;
  }

}
```